# Postgresql array && operator performing slower than expected

Tags: performance, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

### Sample data

I've got 2 tables that I need to join on column that holds array of integers.

```
CREATE TABLE table_array_1 (key1 int, values1 int[]);
CREATE TABLE table_array_2 (key2 int, values2 int[]);
```

One table has small amount of rows but large array sizes:

```
DO $function$
DECLARE
  i int := 0;
BEGIN
  WHILE i < 100 LOOP
      INSERT INTO table_array_1 (key1, values1) values(random(1, i), (SELECT array_agg(random(3000000, 4000000)) FROM (SELECT generate_series(1, random(1, 2000))) lp));
      i := i + 1;
  END LOOP;
END;
$function$
```

Second table has more rows, but small array sizes:

```
DO $function$
DECLARE
  i int := 0;
BEGIN
  WHILE i < 1000 LOOP
      INSERT INTO table_array_2 (key2, values2) values(random(1, i), (SELECT array_agg(random(3000000, 4000000)) FROM (SELECT generate_series(1, random(1, 50))) lp));
      i := i + 1;
  END LOOP;
END;
$function$
```

Function `random(int,int)` returns random integer in range:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION random(int, int)
 RETURNS int
 LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$
   SELECT ($1 + ($2 - $1) * random())::int;
$function$
```

### Tests

I initially try to join them like that [explain](https://explain.depesz.com/s/v3z):

```
SELECT t1.key1, t2.key2
  FROM table_array_1 t1
  JOIN table_array_2 t2 ON t2.values2 && t1.values1
```

But it is much slower (about 100x) than this [explain](https://explain.depesz.com/s/Dugs):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.key1, t2.key2
  FROM (SELECT key1, unnest(values1) AS values1 FROM table_array_1) t1
  JOIN (SELECT key2, unnest(values2) AS values2 FROM table_array_2) t2
    ON t2.values2 = t1.values1
```

There are no indexes on those tables and using `GIN` costs too much to be of any use. GiST does not improve it. This is assuming I would use `intarray` extension.

### Question

Why `unnest` + `distinct` is much faster?

Can I improve performance of array comparison operator method or use something else that wouldn't involve `unnest` + `distinct`? I'm looking for performance improvements and common sense is telling me that those 2 operations should be slower.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the performance difference doesn't really arise from `JOIN` vs `UNNEST` but rather from the condition that you are checking against.

The `&&` array operand is quite resource consuming as it needs to check whether **any** two elements in the arrays overlap (especially when the arrays are "polluted" by `NULL` values). While a plain `=` operand is probably working at byte level, hence being far quicker.

PS: Depending on your Postgres version it could also be that your engine is not optimizing the query plan correctly. ([this, for 9.0, is quite an outstanding example](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/100x-faster-postgres-performance-by-changing-1-line/)).